# iOS Storyboard: Not able to instantiate view controller properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm really having trouble instantiating a custom view controller.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L0MT.png) is my storyboard set up. The third view controller is the one I'm trying to present.

I've tried both of these methods.

1: This results in black screen.

```
var searchController: SearchController = SearchController()
self.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

2: This results in a white, empty view controller popping up.

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let searchController : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchController") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is the code for the actual view controller:

```
class SearchController: UIViewController {

    lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var leftItem = (UIBarButtonItem)(customView: searchBar)
        self.title = "Search"
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }    
}
```

It's very confusing because another custom view controller I am is presented properly while using method #1 above. Why wouldn't it work for this controller?

Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Storyboards you don't need to use `presentViewController` or instantiate your view controllers manually. Instead it's best to use a segue to move from one `UIViewController` to the next.

**1.** In your case, you want a *show* segue, which it looks like you've already done judging by your storyboard.

[image]

**2.** You need to give your segue an `Identifier` which you can do by selecting your segue and going to the *Attributes Editor*.

**3.** To perform your segue just call the following from your first view controller (instead of `presentViewController`).

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourIdHere", sender: self)
```

This will cause the storyboard to instantiate your `SearchViewController` and present it in the way that you've defined for that segue.

**4.** If you want to pass any values to your `SearchViewController`, you can override `prepareForSegue` in `UIViewController`. In your first view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let searchViewController = segue.destinationViewController where segue.identifier == "YourIdHere") {
        // Now you can set variables you have access to in `searchViewController`.
    }
}
```

And that should be it!